# Fortran 90: Assigning a character to a real kind in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90

Apologies for inconvenience , I have resubmitted the code now.
Problem: I am trying to write a program that reads the precipitation from a binary (.DAT) file. It calculates the value of precipitation at each grid and for every grid the maximum value month is returned as output. For example if there was a value of 25 highest in the month of June then our output value should be "Jun".

```
implicit none   
integer,parameter :: ix=44,iy=27,nyr=12  
integer :: ntot  
real :: v_obs(ix,iy,nyr),TestVal,b(ix,iy,nyr),wet(ix,iy)     
real:: Mon(12),Y(12),missing_obs,missing_mod,missing  
integer :: ii,jj,i,j,k,ik,jk,irec,m,n  
character (130) dir,jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec  
data missing_obs/-999000000/  
data missing/-999./    
open(21,file='C:/Fortran/test-dat.dat',access='direct',recl=ix*iy*nyr,form='unformatted')  
open(23,file='C:/wet-month.dat',access='direct',recl=ix*iy*nyr,form='unformatted')  
irec=1  
Do j=1,nyr  
read(21,rec=irec) ((v_obs(ii,jj,j),ii=1,ix),jj=1,iy)  
ntot=0  
do ik=1,nyr  
ntot=ntot+1  
Y(ik)=v_obs(ii,jj,ik)  
enddo  
if (Y(ik) .eq. missing_obs)then  
wet=-999  
go to 199  
endif  
enddo  
Mon(1)=v_obs(ii,jj,1)  
Mon(2)=v_obs(ii,jj,2)  
Mon(3)=v_obs(ii,jj,3)  
Mon(4)=v_obs(ii,jj,4)  
Mon(5)=v_obs(ii,jj,5)  
Mon(6)=v_obs(ii,jj,6)  
Mon(7)=v_obs(ii,jj,7)  
Mon(8)=v_obs(ii,jj,8)  
Mon(9)=v_obs(ii,jj,9)  
Mon(10)=v_obs(ii,jj,10)  
Mon(11)=v_obs(ii,jj,11)  
Mon(12)=v_obs(ii,jj,12)  
TestVal=MAXVAL(Mon)  
If (TestVal .eq. Mon(1)) then   
wet=jan 
else if (TestVal .eq. Mon(2)) Then  
wet=feb  
else if (TestVal .eq. Mon(3)) Then  
wet=mar  
else if (TestVal .eq. Mon(4)) Then  
wet=apr  
else if (TestVal .eq. Mon(5)) Then  
wet=may  
else if (TestVal .eq. Mon(6)) Then  
wet=jun  
else if (TestVal .eq. Mon(7)) Then  
wet=jul  
else if (TestVal .eq. Mon(8)) Then  
wet=aug  
else if (TestVal .eq. Mon(9)) Then  
wet=sep  
else if (TestVal .eq. Mon(10)) Then  
wet=oct  
else if (TestVal .eq. Mon(11)) Then  
wet=nov  
else if (TestVal .eq. Mon(12)) Then  
wet=dec  
endif   
199     continue  
irec=1  
do k=1,nyr  
write(23,rec=irec)((wet(ii,jj),ii=1,ix),jj=1,iy)  
irec=irec+1  
enddo  
close(21)  
close(22)  
end
```

The compliation error says

```
You cannot assign an expression of type CHARACTER(LEN=130) to a variable of type REAL(KIND=1)" i.e: "wet=jan".
```

But I want to save data as character for each grid point.Please help to resolve this error.

Comment: Please format (all) your code correctly, delete any commented-out code and remove excess whitespace.  I, for one, won't even try to help you if you don't have the common sense to make it easy (or easier) for me.  And, if you want me to look at a particular line in your code, such as one in which the compiler finds an error, clearly mark that line.  Do you really expect readers to count lines to find line 101 ?

Comment: Good grief it's worse.  Don't you indent code for comprehensibility ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is all those lines `wet=jan`, `wet=feb`, etc.

As I read from your code `wet` is `real,dimension(44,27)`. `jan` and `feb` are of type `character(130)`. Those are incompatible (as the compiler says).